# How can I see these log messages from a perl script?

Tags: logs

I have this small perl script, I run it as root:

```
use strict;
use Sys::Syslog qw( openlog syslog LOG_INFO );
openlog ('mamamia', 'ndelay', 'mail') or die "Cannot open syslog!";
syslog (LOG_INFO, 'MAMAMIA MAMAMIA MAMAMIA MAMAMIA MAMAMIA MAMAMIA MAMAMIA MAMAMIA!');
```

How can I get to see these log messages? They do not show up in Console or I also cannot see them using `log stream`

I am using macOS Monterey

Comment: based on https://perldoc.perl.org/Sys::Syslog#FUNCTIONS the last arg in `openlog` is a facility. Now you are using "mail", can you check other facilities? they are listed here: https://perldoc.perl.org/Sys::Syslog#Facilities

Comment: I've been able to use the `log` command as in `log show --start "2023-02-22 14:10:00" --process 429 --info` but that requires I already know the pid. Same for using the command, which is `perl5.34` (not very precise). Console.app doesn't show me anything.